# I am trying to delete data from database but my codebase is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

`

```js
import React from 'react';
import useLoadFurnitures from '../../hooks/useLoadFurnitures';

const ManageInventory = ({furniture}) => {
    const { _id, name, img, des, price, quantity, supplier } = furniture;
    const [furnitures, setFurnitures] = useLoadFurnitures(); 
    const handelDelete = (id) => {
        const proceed = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');
        if (proceed) {
            const url = `http://localhost:5000//furnitures/${id}`;
            console.log(url);
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'DELETE'
            })
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    alert('Successfully deleted furniture');
                    const restFurniture = furnitures.filter(furniture._id !== id);
                    setFurnitures(restFurniture);
                    
            })
        }
        
    }
    
    return (
        <div className='mb-4'>
            <div className='img-container border p-4 rounded-lg'>
                <img className='w-full' src={img} alt="" />
                <h4 className='text-center  mt-2 text-xl font-bold'>{name}</h4>
                <h4 className='text-center '>{des}</h4>
                <h4 className='text-center font-bold'>Price: $ {price}</h4>
                <h4 className='text-center font-bold'>Quantity: {quantity}</h4>
                <h4 className='text-center font-bold'>Supplier: {supplier}</h4>
                <div className='flex justify-center'>
                <button onClick={()=>handelDelete(furniture._id) } className='bg-[red] px-2 py-1 mt-4 mr-2 text-white font-bold'>Delete</button> 
                </div>
                
            </div>   
        </div>
    );
};

export default ManageInventory;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

`I am trying to delete data both from database and from my UI. I have an error i dont understand how to fixed it . I am using ReactJS for front End and NodeJS for back-end server and MongoBD as a nosql database. What should i do to fixed this error? I am attaching My screenshot to show what is the error is.[When i click on the delete button this error occur in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh3bt.png)

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The 404 is your real problem. Are you sure you are listening for DELETE requests?  You should show the code for the delete endpoint. 

(The double slash before furnitures could be the reason. A spelling error could be the reason. No such document in the database could be the reason.)


The "Unexpected token < in json..." means you are getting a html page instead of a json-page, but probably it's just the 404-error page, so you should just ignore it until you solve the 404.

Comment: i added the codebase of my client side hope it will help you to give me the proper solution

Comment: The main issue as @ippi mentioned is 404, means you are putting wrong URL for endpoint.
There is a slight mistake in the URL you shared, it should be:
``` const url = `http://localhost:5000/furnitures/${id}`;```

Maybe this help, but still you need to match the URL as well as confirm if your backend is accepting DELETE request agains this url.